# How to compare two fields and then update row

Tags: mysql

I have 2 fields in my table(openDate and closeDate) and I want to compare this dates and the execute an update query I dont have to knowledge about MySQL so thats the reason of why I dont write code.

In MSSQL I could declare 2 variables and do this for example

```
declare @date1 nvarchar
set @date1 = Select openDate from table1 
declare @date2 nvarchar
set @date2 = Select closeDate from table1
```

then IF (@date1 < @date2)
query here

But in MySQL I dont have idea.

Comment: use: **UPDATE table1 set fieldA=1234 WHERE openDate < closeDate;**

Comment: I can use this query with a MySQL Event without a problem?

Comment: yes, but :-) it changes ALL rows where openDate < closeDate. if you want only to change 1 row add LIMIT 1 at the end.

Comment: also when the event runs every minute mysql find each time the same rows.  the condition openDate < closeDate is always true

Comment: Yeah actually I want to update all the rows where openDate < closeDate, thanks bro!